# Node js sql query inner join

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Can you help me about this sql query about the INNER JOIN.
The result return error

```js
connection.query("SELECT caracavis.caracname FROM caracavis WHERE firstcaturl ='" + req.body[0].firstcatname + "' AND secondcaturl = '" + req.body[0].secondcatname + "' AND thirdcaturl = '" + req.body[0].thirdcatname + "' AND fourthcaturl = '" + req.body[0].fourthcatname + "' AND fifthcaturl = '" + req.body[0].fifthcatname + "' INNER JOIN critereproducts ON caracavis.caracname = critereproducts.nameurl", function (error, results, fields) {
    if (!!error) {
     console.log('erreur');
    } else {
     console.log(results);
     // res.json(results);
    };
   });
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What is the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` comes before `WHERE`.

```
SELECT caracavis.caracname
FROM caracavis 
INNER JOIN critereproducts 
ON caracavis.caracname = critereproducts.nameurl
WHERE ...
```

Comment: It works ! I can't accept now, should wait 7min. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Off on a tangent, but you can do join syntax in the WHERE clause, but you wouldn't use JOIN statements. You'd just list the tables in the FROM clause, then in the WHERE clause you'd enforce the relationship, which is very similar to what you attempted but a mix of the two. Recommended approach is always use ANSI Join syntax, e.g. INNER JOIN, over the old style.